# How to apply triangular box-shadow to triangle shape in react native

Tags: react-native

I have created a triangle shape in react native using following code.

```
<View style={cardStyle.cardLeftNotch}></View>

cardLeftNotch: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderTopWidth: 7,
    borderRightWidth: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 7,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -10,
    top: 21,
    elevation: 4
}
```

But, the shadow is not applying in triangular shape. I am using android phone for testing.

Comment: did you find a solution? and was my solution helpful?

Comment: I used an image instead of CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it but I think [react-native-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow) can do it.

But if you want to do it manually, you can't carve the shadow with only the elevation in android so you have to create each side's shadow manually, it's a headache. One way to do it is create a shadowed `view` on each side and rotate them and then combine them to make a triangle:

```
<View style={cardStyle.side1}></View>
<View style={cardStyle.side2}></View>
<View style={cardStyle.side3}></View>

side1: {
    width: 1,
    height: 50,
    left: 300,
    top: 21,
    elevation: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
    transform: [
        {
            rotate: '30deg'
        }
    ],
    position: 'absolute',
},

side2: {
    width: 50,
    height: 1,
    left: 300,
    top: 45,
    elevation: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
    transform: [
        {
            rotate: '60deg'
        }
    ],
    position: 'absolute',
},

side3: {
    width: 48,
    height: 1,
    left: 287,
    top: 70,
    elevation: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.01)',
    position: 'absolute',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I fell into this post first while researching I want to add to the post and give an answer to aid the **IOS** only like me

```
        <View style={styles.shadow}>
            <View
                style={[
                    styles.triangle,
                    {
                        borderLeftWidth: width,
                        borderBottomWidth: height,
                        borderBottomColor: color,
                        transform: angle ? [{ rotate: `${angle}deg` }] : undefined,
                    },
                ]}
            />
        </View>
```

```
    triangle: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderStyle: "solid",
        borderLeftColor: "transparent",
    },
    shadow: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        ...Platform.select({
            ios: {
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: {
                    width: -1,
                    height: -1,
                },
                shadowOpacity: 0.5,
                shadowRadius: 3,
            }
        }),
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

A straightforward method would be to use the `filter` property, as it takes transparency into consideration regarding the shadow's shape;

```css
.tri {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 7px;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    border-bottom-width: 7px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #f88;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 21px;
    
    filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="tri"></div>
```

Note that large shadow radius values, or large elements with shadows may have adverse effects on performance, so it's best to use this sparingly.

Comment: `filter` doesn't work in react native, your code is in react not react native

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR oof, you're right. However, there is some work being done to get svg filter support on react-native, and apparently there might even be a working branch; https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/150#issuecomment-522465114